# Using one of the TPT subclasses as TPH

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6

Using EF6 code first, I have a model which looks as shown in the diagram.

[image]

Here, `a` is the primary key.

I would like to use a [TBT strategy](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) so that A, AB and AC all map to different tables, while AB1 and AB2 are distinguished using a discriminator column in AB.

I tried to map them using the following Fluent API code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AB>().ToTable("AB");
modelBuilder.Entity<AC>().ToTable("AC");
```

This did give me 3 tables as I wished, but the discriminator column shows up in A instead of AB, showing (Undefined) for the AC entities. How can I make it show up in AB?